# Titlepage: text left of picture

Tags: wrapfigure

I tried to get a titlepage similar to the one in the picture, which I made with MS Word.

The problem is that I can't put the text on the left of the profile-picture in the way it is in the eaxmple-picture.
I tried it with "wrapfigure", but I didn't manage to put the "name" at the bottom (left) of the profile-picture and all the other text on the bottom of the picture.
Is this even possible?

Thanks for your help.

best reagrds

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a `\hfill` between the name and the image:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\hrule\vfill
{\centering\Huge\bfseries  XYZ\par}
\vfill\hrule\vfill\vfill
NAME NAME \hfill \includegraphics[width=8cm,angle=90]{example-image}
\vfill
XYZ Street 100\par
60795 XYZ\par
Tel: 0101010 0101010\par 
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach of minipages:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
Text here ...
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
Picture here ...
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Adding an `\hfill` or such between these may be advisable, as could be adding a vertically alignment option.

Comment: Why four  environments?  Try `Name Name  \hfill \includegraphics[witdh=4cm]{example-image}`. It is  simpler and it  will produce exactly the  layout of the image.

Comment: What if you need more than the "name" left of the picture. Would this work with `\hfill`, too?